# Issue with adding custom ringtone to Ringtonemanager for Android app development?

Tags: java, android, ringtone, ringtonemanager

I am trying to add a custom ringtone for my android app. All i have done is created a raw folder in res directory and added a mp3 file there as a ringtone using below code. some how only default notification tone from Android app has been played on calling this ringtone. Any help would be highly appreciated.

private synchronized void startRinging() {

```
    try {


        Uri ringtoneUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/ringnow.mp3");
        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, ringtoneUri
        );
        r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), ringtoneUri);


        if (r != null) {
            r.play();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private synchronized void stopRinging() {

   r.stop();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you shouldn`t write ".mp3" in your URI